# Pandas: extract values from column, according to value of another column, and separate into separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe indexed by date, with columns of flood size (0-3), and precipitation (ppt):

```
                Size    ppt
date
2017-09-11      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-12      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-13      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-14      1.0     34.709998
2017-09-15      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-16      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-17      0.0     0.000000
2017-09-18      0.0     0.600000
2017-09-19      3.0     157.439998
```

I need to separate the data according to whether a flood occurred ('Size'=1,2 or 3), or no flood occurred ('Size'=0), to give me two separate sets of precipitation data associated with flood or no flood.

I appreciate this is probably quite basic, but I can't seem to find the right answers...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverting boolean mask by `~`:

```
mask = df['Size'].eq(0)
#alternative
#mask = df['Size'] == 0
df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]
```

EDIT:

For multiple boolean mask use:

```
m1 = df['Size'].eq(0)
m2 = df['ppt'].eq(0)

#alternative
#m1 = df['Size'] == 0
#m2 = df['ppt'] == 0

SizePos = df[m1 & m2]
dSizeZero_PptPosf2 = df[m1 & ~m2]
SizeZero_PptZero = df[~m1]

print (SizePos)
            Size  ppt
date                 
2017-09-11   0.0  0.0
2017-09-12   0.0  0.0
2017-09-13   0.0  0.0
2017-09-15   0.0  0.0
2017-09-16   0.0  0.0
2017-09-17   0.0  0.0

print (dSizeZero_PptPosf2)
            Size  ppt
date                 
2017-09-18   0.0  0.6

print (SizeZero_PptZero)
date                        
2017-09-14   1.0   34.709998
2017-09-19   3.0  157.439998
```

Comment: down the line in my analysis I am running into trouble, so wonder if you might have a suggestion? I am trying to put these separated data into box plots, but I am getting the error:  'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' Do you understand what is happening here?

Comment: Yes I think I should ask a new question, I am finding the same issue with the other answers on this thread. Thanks for your input! I have accepted your answer (I actually tried to do it earlier but you answered so quickly it told me I had to wait haha)

Comment: @SHV_la - If performance is important, dont use `groupby`. Simple use boolean indexing for 3 DataFrames. But if want some interesting, but slowier solution, use groupby + np.select - more code, obvilously slowier. It is up to you, what need.

Answer (score 2):

#### `groupby`

We can iterate through the `groupby` object after grouping by the boolean evaluation of `Size` being `0` or not.  When we assign this to other names (`df1, df2 = ...`) the resulting iterable is split into its two parts.

```
df1, df2 = (d for _, d in df.groupby(df.Size.eq(0)))
```

Print them to see

```
print(df1, df2, sep='\n\n')

            Size         ppt
date                        
2017-09-14   1.0   34.709998
2017-09-19   3.0  157.439998

            Size  ppt
date                 
2017-09-11   0.0  0.0
2017-09-12   0.0  0.0
2017-09-13   0.0  0.0
2017-09-15   0.0  0.0
2017-09-16   0.0  0.0
2017-09-17   0.0  0.0
2017-09-18   0.0  0.6
```

For the purposes of explanation

```
for name, d in df.groupby(df.Size.eq(0)):
  print(name, d, '=' * 40, sep='\n\n')

False

            Size         ppt
date                        
2017-09-14   1.0   34.709998
2017-09-19   3.0  157.439998

========================================
True

            Size  ppt
date                 
2017-09-11   0.0  0.0
2017-09-12   0.0  0.0
2017-09-13   0.0  0.0
2017-09-15   0.0  0.0
2017-09-16   0.0  0.0
2017-09-17   0.0  0.0
2017-09-18   0.0  0.6

========================================
```

Comment: Looks nice. Although if you can please explain me the logic , the use of `_` . Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Notice that in the latter explanation I use `name` instead of `_`.  We typically use the variable name `_` for things we intend to discard or not use.

Comment: In my opinion really overcomplicated solution, so not upvoting.

Comment: I respect your opinion (-:  However, the reason I like it is that it is an easy way to generate several dataframes at one time.  The value is up to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of dataframes:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(np.where(df['Size'].eq(0), 'ppt_negative', 'ppt_positive'))))
```

The benefit of this approach is you are explicitly linking related data structures, which may aid subsequent manipulations, transportability, etc.

Result:

```
{'ppt_negative':          date  Size  ppt
                 0  2017-09-11   0.0  0.0
                 1  2017-09-12   0.0  0.0
                 2  2017-09-13   0.0  0.0
                 4  2017-09-15   0.0  0.0
                 5  2017-09-16   0.0  0.0
                 6  2017-09-17   0.0  0.0
                 7  2017-09-18   0.0  0.6,

 'ppt_positive':          date  Size         ppt
                 3  2017-09-14   1.0   34.709998
                 8  2017-09-19   3.0  157.439998}
```

---

More elaborate differentiation is possible via `np.select`:

```
m1 = df['Size'].eq(0)
m2 = df['ppt'].eq(0)

conds = [m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2, ~m1]
choices = ['SizeZero_PptZero', 'SizeZero_PptPos', 'SizePos']

dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(np.select(conds, choices))))
```

Result:

```
{'SizePos':          date  Size         ppt
            3  2017-09-14   1.0   34.709998
            8  2017-09-19   3.0  157.439998,

 'SizeZero_PptPos':          date  Size  ppt
                    7  2017-09-18   0.0  0.6,

 'SizeZero_PptZero':          date  Size  ppt
                     0  2017-09-11   0.0  0.0
                     1  2017-09-12   0.0  0.0
                     2  2017-09-13   0.0  0.0
                     4  2017-09-15   0.0  0.0
                     5  2017-09-16   0.0  0.0
                     6  2017-09-17   0.0  0.0}
```

Comment: I appreciate the `dict(tuple(...`

Comment: @piRSquared, Yeh I personally find it a life-saver. Having to remember what `df1`, `df2` mean in a long bit of code is painful.

Comment: @jpp thank you for this, is it possible to take this further by splitting the 'ppt_negative' into two sets, one with '0' ppt, and the other containing values '>0' ppt? Basically, I am not interested in days when nothing happens...

Comment: @jpp very clever! Thank you :)